# Get total upvotes for each user for all his posts

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

The database structure is as follows:

### users

```
[id] [name]    [etc...]
1    Echolot   ...
2    AnotherUser  ...
```

### posts

```
[id] [user_id] [title] [etc...]
1    1         Post1   ...
2    1         Post2   ...
```

### posts_upvotes

```
[id] [post_id] [user_id (user who voted)] [value (1 or 0 or -1)]
1    1         1                          1
2    1         2                          -1
3    2         1                          1
4    2         2                          1
```

I'm trying to get a list of all users and their total amount of upvotes `sum(value)`gathered by all their posts like so:

```
id: 1
name: Echolot
upvoteCount: 2

id: 2
name: AnotherUser
upvoteCount: 0
```

I have tried using the following query but without success, I get wrong values and not the right amount of results:

```
          SELECT joinedUsers.id, joinedPosts.postCount, joinedPostsUpvotes.upvoteCount
          FROM users joinedUsers
          inner join (
            SELECT user_id, id, count(id) as postCount
            FROM posts
            GROUP BY user_id, id
          ) joinedPosts on joinedPosts.user_id = joinedUsers.id
          inner join (
            SELECT post_id, sum(value) as upvoteCount
            FROM posts_upvotes
            GROUP BY post_id
          ) joinedPostsUpvotes on joinedPostsUpvotes.post_id = joinedPosts.id
          GROUP BY joinedUsers.id, joinedPosts.postCount, joinedPostsUpvotes.upvoteCount
```

Thank you in advance for any hints or solutions.

EDIT: Added test data and expected results.

Comment: show a test data and desired output.

Comment: @reds Thanks for your input. I added some data and the desired output to my question.

Comment: So you're counting the upvotes a users casted, not those casted by others on his posts?

Comment: @StefanoZanini No, I want to count the upvotes casted on all of users post. Like a total points overview.

Comment: Then I think your expected output is wrong... user 1 has post 1 and the sum of upvotes on that post is 0. Am I missing something?

Comment: @StefanoZanini user 1 has also post 2 which has the upvotes sum of 2 which results in the net sum of 2

Comment: Sorry, I misred, you're absolutely right. Some of the answers should give you the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all those subqueries, you can just use a couple `left join` between `user`, `post` and `post_upvotes`:

```
SELECT  t1.id, t1.name, count(distinct t2.id), sum(t3.value)
FROM    users t1
LEFT JOIN
        posts t2
ON      t1.id = t2.user_id
LEFT JOIN    
        posts_upvotes t3
ON      t2.id = t3.post_id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name
```

The use of `left join` instead of `inner join` ensures you that users with no posts or posts with no votes will be displayed as well.

Comment: This works beautifully thank you very much... I had to remove the `t2.` from `t2.count(distinct t2.id)` to make it work but else it's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be something like this if you want the count of the amount of times someone voted (not tested)

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, COUNT(posts_upvotes.id) as upvoteCount
      FROM users
      INNER JOIN posts_upvotes ON posts_upvotes.user_id = users.id
      GROUP BY users.id
```

Or this if you want the sum of the value of the upvotes:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, SUM(posts_upvotes.id) as upvoteSum
      FROM users
      INNER JOIN posts_upvotes ON posts_upvotes.user_id = users.id
      GROUP BY users.id
```

Or in Laravel you could use the Query Builder: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries

Something like this:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->join('posts_upvotes', 'users.id', '=', 'posts_upvotes.user_id'))
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.name', DB::raw('COUNT(posts_upvotes) as upvoteCount'))
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would do the trick for you:

```
SELECT u.id,
  u.name,
  COUNT(p.id)
  SUM(pu.value)
FROM users AS u
JOIN posts AS p
ON u.id = p.user_id
JOIN posts_upvotes AS pu
ON p.id = pu.post_id
GROUP BY u.id,
  u.name
```

If I am not missing something in your question.